# Getting Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref not implementing parent interface

Tags: java, dependency-injection, glassfish, ejb

I'm trying to figure out why I need to implement both of these interfaces in order to avoid deployment issues.

### Java Code

**ExamplePlanAssembler.java**

```
@Local
public interface ExamplePlanAssembler {
   ExamplePlan toBO(ExamplePlanEntity entity);
}
```

**ExtendedExamplePlanAssembler.java**

```
@Local
public interface ExtendedExamplePlanAssembler 
extends ExamplePlanAssembler{
   ExtExamplePlan toBO(ExamplePlanEntity entity, ExtExamplePlanEntity extEntity);
}
```

**ExtendedExamplePlanAssemblerImpl.java**

```
@Stateless
public class ExtendedExamplePlanAssemblerImpl 
implements ExtendedExamplePlanAssembler {
   /* Method impls removed */
}
```

**ExamplePlanServiceImpl.java**

```
@Stateless
public class ExamplePlanServiceImpl 
implements ExamplePlanService {
   private ExamplePlanAssembler examplePlanAssembler ;
   @EJB
   public void setAssembler(ExamplePlanAssembler examplePlanAssembler) {
       this.examplePlanAssembler = examplePlanAssembler;
    }
}
```

### Deployment Error

```
[#|.507-0500|SEVERE|gf3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.org.glassfish.deployment.common
|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-7;|Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref name=
com.myco.services.business.ExampleServiceImpl/examplePlanAssembler,Local 3.x interface =
com.myco.services.assembly.ExamplePlanAssembler,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session|#]

[#|.508-0500|SEVERE|gf3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server
|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-7;|Exception while deploying the app [mycoservicesear]|#]

[#|.508-0500|SEVERE|gf3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server
|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-7;|Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref name=
com.myco.services.business.ExampleServiceImpl/examplePlanAssembler,Local 3.x interface =
com.myco.services.assembly.ExamplePlanAssembler,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref name=
com.myco.services.business.ExampleServiceImpl/examplePlanAssembler,Local 3.x interface =
com.myco.services.assembly.ExamplePlanAssembler,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session


[#|.516-0500|SEVERE|gf3.1.2|javax...gf.deployment.admin
|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-7;|Exception while deploying the app [mycoservicesear] : Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref name=
com.myco.services.business.ExampleServiceImpl/examplePlanAssembler,Local 3.x interface =
com.myco.services.assembly.ExamplePlanAssembler,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session|#]
```

### The Fix?!

If I change my interface impl to implement not only the `ExtendedExamplePlanAssembler` interface, but also the parent `ExamplePlanAssembler` interface, my deployment error disappears.

**ExtendedExamplePlanAssemblerImpl.java (v2)**

```
@Stateless
public class ExtendedExamplePlanAssemblerImpl 
implements ExtendedExamplePlanAssembler,  ExamplePlanAssembler{
   /* Method impls removed */
}
```

### The Question

*Why* does adding the parent interface to my `implements` declaration resolve deployment issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EJB Spec says so,

As an example, the client views exposed by a particular session bean are not inherited by a subclass that
also happens to define a session bean.

```
@Stateless
public class A implements Foo { ... }
@Stateless
public class B extends A implements Bar { ... }
```

Assuming Foo and Bar are local business interfaces and there is no associated deployment descriptor,
session bean A exposes local business interface Foo and session bean B exposes local business interface
Bar, but not Foo.

Reference [here](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr318/index.html). Section 4.9.2.1 of EJB3.1 Spec

Comment: Your reference link didn't really point to something directly that supports your claim.  I'll leave this open for a couple of days.  If no one provides a better answer or you can provide a deep link to the exact wording in the spec, I'll award the answer to you.

Comment: well the above text is copy of ejb 3.1 spec. search for the text...may be searc afain:-)

Comment: Thanks.  This link also helped a bit. http://weblogs.java.net/blog/sekhar/archive/2009/02/jboss_to_glassf.html

Comment: However.... the examples given don't really cover my case.  The examples are of class inheritance with each class specifying a different interface.  In my example, I have Interface inheritance with the class implementing the child interface.  Minor difference.

Answer (score 0):

you can not extend an interface 
I need you to try implementing the interface (you can implement both interfaces in the same bean class)
but for now you need to replace the keyword "extends" with "implements"

```
@Local
public interface ExtendedExamplePlanAssembler 
 extends ExamplePlanAssembler{
  ExtExamplePlan toBO(ExamplePlanEntity entity, ExtExamplePlanEntity  extEntity);
}
```