# Java EE Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, java-ee-7

I'm getting the following error:

```
Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [snel-transport-web] : Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref name=UserFacade,Local 3.x interface =null,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session
```

I had googled the error and I had arrived on the following questions on Stack Overflow:

[EJB Injection failure on deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167712/ejb-injection-failure-on-deploy)

[Getting Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref not implementing parent interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823527/getting-cannot-resolve-reference-local-ejb-ref-not-implementing-parent-interface)

I assume it has something to do with my annotations `@remote` and `@LocalBean`.

Here is the code that I currently have:

AbstractFacade.java:

```
@Remote
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }  
}
```

UserFacade.java:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class UserFacade extends AbstractFacade<User> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "com.mycompany_snel-transport-ejb_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public UserFacade() {
        super(User.class);
    }   
}
```

AuthCtrl.java:

```
@Path("/auth")
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class AuthCtrl extends Application {

    com.mycompany.UserFacade userFacade = lookupUserFacadeBean();

    /**
     * 
     * @return 
     */
    @GET
    @Path("/user")
    public String getHelloMsg() {
        return "test";
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param message
     * @return
     */
    @POST
    @Path("/register")
    public String register(String message) {
        // Register user
//        userFacade.create(entity);

        return "done registering";
    }

    private com.mycompany.UserFacade lookupUserFacadeBean() {
        try {
            Context c = new InitialContext();
            return (com.mycompany.UserFacade) c.lookup("java:global/com.mycompany_snel-transport-ear_ear_1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.mycompany_snel-transport-ejb_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOT/UserFacade!com.mycompany.UserFacade");
        } catch (NamingException ne) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", ne);
            throw new RuntimeException(ne);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `LocalBean` that implements `Remote` interface (in this case extends the class, but it still applies). Try changing either `Remote` to `Local` or `LocalBean` to `RemoteBean`. If that doesn't help try deleting annotation from abstract class altogether.

Comment: I had tried your first option, but it didn't fixed it. Also `RemoteBean` doesn't exist? I don't understand your last option. You mean that I delete `@remote` from `AbstractFacade.java` and `@LocalBean` from `UserFacade.java`? If that's what you meant, then that also didn't fixed my problem.

Comment: No, leave `@LocalBean`, it's ok, just remove `@Remote` from abstract class. `@LocalBean` is used for a class with no-interface view, so it should work.

Comment: I had removed `@Remote` from the abstract class. And I have `@LocalBean` in `UserFacade.java`. But it still didn't fixed it..

Comment: Well I don't know then, last thing that comes to my mind: put `@Local` on abstract class (just `@Local`, nothing else) and remove `@LocalBean` from `UserFacade`. That's how you do it when bean implements interface, but with abstract class i'm not sure.

Comment: Unfortunately that also didn't fixed it. Maybe it has something to do with my `persistence.xml` ? Here is my `persistence.xml` file link: http://pastebin.com/DgX0vMk0

Comment: Ok, last idea: delete all annotations from abstract class, create interface called `UserFacadeInterface` with no methods, annotate it with `@Local`, then leave only `@Stateless` on `UserFacade` (remove `@LocalBean`) and make it implement the new interface (with `implements UserFacadeInteraface`).